# Custom Gtk Widget with template UI

Tags: gtk, gtk3, subclassing, gtkbuilder

I've created a custom Gtk Widget with a template, and I want to use it on other Gtk Builder file.

What I've done:

- Wrote a .ui file with `<template class="G3JAMinScenes" parent="GtkBox">`
- Wrote widget source code (.c/.h)

when I create it with `g3jamin_scenes_new` the widget works as expected, the problem is that I want to add it as child of a window using Gtk Builder, so I wrote:

```
...
<child>
    <object class="G3JAMinScenes" parent="GtkBox" id="scnes">
    </object>
</child>
...
```

but it throws an error when I try to run:

```
Gtk-CRITICAL **: Error building template class 'G3JAMinAppWindow' for an instance of type 'G3JAMinAppWindow': Invalid object type `G3JAMinScenes'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't been able to find any official answer to this in any documentation. I went digging through the GTK+ source and found a few things though.

When `GtkBuilder` sees a type it doesn't know about yet, it tries to obtain a function that returns the relevant`GType`. It will try a couple of heuristics to determine what function to call. If you are using one of the `G_DEFINE_TYPE` family of macros, it will generate the necessary `mywidget_get_type` style function that is needed.  If you are doing something weird, you can also specify the function in the `type-func` attribute for the object in your ui file.

But, for simple programs that probably isn't going to work (at least on Linux) because the compiler probably isn't going to export the function in the dynamic symbol table, and so `GtkBuilder` won't be able to find it. So you are left with a few options.

1. Call `mywidget_get_type()` somewhere early in your application. This will register the type in the `GObject` type system and `GtkBuilder` will be able to find it. I am using a subclass of `GtkApplication`, so I'm calling it in my `myapp_class_init`. This feels a little bit like a hack, but I settled on this solution because it seems like it should be portable to every situation.
2. If you are using GCC, link the final executable with `-rdynamic`. This will put all symbols in the dynamic symbol table so the magic described above will allow `GtkBuilder` to find it.
3. Build your widget in a shared library. I haven't tried this one, but I believe it should work for the same reason that `-rdynamic` works.

Comment: Instead of calling `mywidget_get_type()` somewhere, you should use `g_type_ensure()` with the type of the internal child inside the instance initialization function of the widget class. For instance: https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtkfilechooserwidget.c#n8598

Comment: Needless to say, ebassi is right. Calling thing_get_type() before gtk_widget_init_template() solved it for me.

Comment: Link in Ebassi's comment is broken, so here is a good one: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/blob/3.18.1/gtk/gtkfilechooserwidget.c#L8598